# How to list folder contents in Qml?

Tags: application-development, qml, ubuntu-sdk

I'm trying to rewrite a part of the notes-app in order to store notes directly in the file system. 
But I'd like to be able to list files in a folder, not in order to display them, but to process them in a javascript function.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick example of how to display the contents of a folder using a [FolderListModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel1-folderlistmodel.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 1.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import Ubuntu.Components.ListItems 0.1 as ListItem

MainView {
    id: root
    width: units.gu(50)
    height: units.gu(75)

    Page {
        id: home
        visible: true
        title: "Files"

        FolderListModel {
            id: folderModel
            folder: "/"
            nameFilters: [ "*" ]
        }

        ListView {
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: folderModel
            delegate: ListItem.Standard {
                text: model.fileName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like:

[image: folder view]

Now of course, you want to do something with this information. Unfortunately, you can't iterate over the model as simply as you'd like to as [explained in this post on the Beru developer's blog](http://rschroll.github.io/beru/2013/08/20/iterating-over-a-folderlistmodel.html). He helpfully shows how to use the `Repeater` component:

```
    Repeater {
        model: folderModel

        Component {
            Item {
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    // Do something interesting here...
                    console.log(fileName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```